# How do I fix an error when sending an email in django?

Tags: django

I have a PasswordReset setup in django for when I forget my password, but when I test it, I get this error.
[WinError 10061] Could not connect because the target computer refused.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apptest'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server listening on port 25 on the host which is running Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be like this. You're using `SMTP`, so try connecting to services that offer this. For example for gmail, the settings look like this.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email_at@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_password'
```

The alternative could be testing via the file or console [`back-end`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#console-backend).

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Would it be safer to create a gmail specifically for this app?

Comment: I did the same, but unfortunately recently gmail has been blocking access to the application. You can use alternative SMTP or try to set up two-step verification on gmail (it is possible that then the password for the application will work).